# RichTextBox color selected lines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I am new to windows Forms. I am using VS 2008, C# to write a RichTextBox.
I want to be able to color each line with a different color as I write to the RichTextBox. Can someone point me to samples.
Thanks

```
foreach (string file in myfiles)
{
  // As I process my files
  // richTextBox1.Text += "My processing results";
  if(file == "somefileName")
  {
    // Color above entered line or enter new colored line
  }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `SelectionColor` before you append, something like:

```
    int line = 0;
    foreach (string file in myfiles)
    {
        // Whatever method you want to choose a color, here
        // I'm just alternating between red and blue
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = 
            line % 2 == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Blue;

        // AppendText is better than rtb.Text += ...
        richTextBox1.AppendText(file + "\r\n");
        line++;
    }
```

Comment: +1. VB.Net users should remember that \r\n is escaping in C#. Write .AppendText(file & vbCrLf) in VB

Comment: As mentioned in the code comment, using += seems to reset all of the text colour that was already set in the box, so the AppendText method is what did the trick.